# if <> ... What am I missing

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, logical-operators

I cannot find anything that gives me any reason to assume that this wouldn't work. No matter what, this always evaluates the code inside the if statement.

I tried putting everything in () I tried separating each statement with (). No matter what it always runs the code inside the if statement. What am I missing?

```
' Update by Adam W. Schneider 11/10/2017
If strDrawingSize <> "T" Or strDrawingSize <> "Y" Or strDrawingSize <> "Z" Or strDrawingSize <> "M" Or strDrawingSize <> "P" Or strDrawingSize <> "S" Or strDrawingSize <> "N" Or strDrawingSize <> "W" Or strDrawingSize <> "X" Or strDrawingSize <> "R" Or strDrawingSize <> "O" Then

    ' Update by Adam Schneider 08/24/2017
    cboRefDrawingSize.Text = cboDrawingSize.Text

End If
```

I know thats an ugly if statement, I tried to use negative logic with a case statement but that didn't work either.

Comment: I think all your `Or`s should be `And`. Every string is not-equal to all but one of those at the least.

Comment: Read the logic out loud. "If something **is not** "T" **or** that same thing **is not** "Y"..." - can that ever be false?

Comment: `If strDrawingSize <> "T" Or strDrawingSize <> "Y"...` It's always going to not be equal to at least one of those things. You need AND logic.

Comment: i am retarded lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to check if `strDrawingSize` is not any one of the desired letters. If that is the case, then use the IndexOf method on the desired letters to compare if it is -1:

```
If "TYZMPSNWXRO".IndexOf(strDrawingSize) = -1 Then
    cboRefDrawingSize.Text = cboDrawingSize.Text
End If
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8n8tj3)

This is how it works: Essentially a String is a collection of Char values, the IndexOf method returns the index of a given value inside the collection and returns -1 if the value is not found.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your code will always execute because you're using OR instead of AND.

The cleaner way is to use a `Select Case`:

```
Select Case strDrawingSize
    Case "T", "Y", "Z", "M", "P", "S", "N", "W", "X", "R", "O"
    Case Else
            ' Update by Adam Schneider 08/24/2017
            cboRefDrawingSize.Text = cboDrawingSize.Text
End Select
```

Comment: This is an OK solution in that it works, but take a look at my example of an even cleaner solution.